# What is the most efficient way to call an object's state specific code block?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I've got a big list (30-50) of game objects that change between 5-7 states in a sudo-sequential order that radically alters their behavior.

My initial naive approach was to give each game object a State variable and then every action command would take it through an if-else block to find the correct action corresponding to state.

Option 1 (Naive Approach)

```
class Bot:
    def action(self):
        if self.state == 1:
            action1()
            if condition1_to_2():
                self.state = 2
        elif self.state == 2:
            action2()
        #...

list_of_bots = [Bot(), Bot(), ...]

for bot in list_of_bots:
    bot.action()
```

But I thought, with 50 game objects, doesn't this if-else traversing begin to take up significant time?

Couldn't I speed up performance by going straight to state's correct code?

The only way I can think of implementing this is to use inheritance (either an interface or subclasses) and make each game state of each game object its own subclass, destroying and creating a new object every time it changes state.

Option 2 (Inheritance)

```
class Bot:
    def action(): raise NotImplementedError

class Bot1(Bot):
    def action():
       action1()

class Bot2(Bot):
    def action():
       action2()
#...

list_of_bots = [Bot1(), Bot2(), ...]

for bot in list_of_bots:
    bot.action()
```

This way each game object wouldn't have to check what state it was in every tick of the game which saves like 300 operations per tick.

My only problem is that it feels a bit like overkill making so many new classes. Is there a more compact but equally efficient solution to this problem?

I thought a state dictionary or list (assuming those give an O(1) access time), but how can you link a list to a code block?

Option 3 (Impossible?)

```
class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
       self.action_list = [action1(), action2(), ...]
       self.state = 1

    def action():
        self.action_list[self.state]
```

The solution must be done in raw python3 (no pip install).

Comment: You could use function references in your dictionary/list which allow you to then call the function after retreiving it. Just store `self.action_list = [action1, action2, ...]`. As long as these functions don't require different parameters then that should work fine to do `self.action_list[self.state]()`

Comment: My game objects need to see the game_map in order to decide where to move, also as python objects, the method needs a `self` param, right?

Comment: The self param get's passed in automatically as long as you've created an instance of the class. You would need to store the action list like this then: `self.action_list = [self.action1, self.action2, ...]` and then call it the same way.

Comment: I guess I can just "pass" parameters as instance variables `self.game_map = game_map \n return self.action_list[self.state]` not pretty, but effective don't you think?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by that. If your `game_map` is an object/list then whenever you update it somewhere else it is still updating the same `game_map` in memory. As long as you didn't do a copy of it. So when you do your initialization of the bot you give it a `game_map`, that should always be the same object that you don't need to overwrite each time.

Comment: I wish I could write out code blocks better in the comments. My example code excludes a parameter in `action()`, it should really be `action(game_map)` where a controller class calls the action func on each game object while passing the current state of the game map. The actions depend on the environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182605/discussion-between-csstudent7782-and-karl).

Answer (score 0):

Your Option 3 can work with function references, however I am not sure if this program structure is the best to use. But to accomplish storing a list of function references you can do so like this:

```
class Bot:
    def __init__(self, game_map):
       self.action_list = [self.action1, self.action2]  # Stores function references
       self.state = 1
       self.game_map = game_map  # Pass in game_map object that the class can use

    def action(self):
        self.action_list[self.state]()  # Calls function reference

    def action1(self):
        # Does something

    def action2(self):
        # Does something
```

Edit: I added in an example of how to pass in the `game_map` object you mentioned in the comments. You can then use `self.game_map` wherever in your action functions which will be the same object your game controller is updating as long as you are modifying that map each time instead of creating a new one.

Comment: I think I'm ultimately going to use this (with a dictionary and an enumerator class) if no one objects for performance reasons. Thanks for the tip, never knew I actually could do this.